# put tests/, tox.ini in distribution tar.gz

Tags: python, packaging, setup.py

I have a Python package with a `tests/` folder and a `tox.ini`. I would like users to be able to run tests, so I'd like to include those into the distributed `.tar.gz`.

How to achieve that? `MANIFEST.in`? Some entry in `setup()`? Or is this silly to begin with?

Answer (score 1):

```
include tox.ini
include tests/*
```

in MANIFEST.in